# Rails Adding a column to a table at runtime

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

What are the cons of allowing a user to add a column to a table in the database at runtime in a production environment. Is there a correct way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Normally when using a relational DB we never extend the DB at runtime.

- At high performance, this is basically impossible (requires modifying the entire dataset, so the request will hang for the user)
- Besides that, we do not really want to give users the power to grow our dataset (adding a new column means requiring an extra field for every row in the DB).

However, some relational DBs like Postgres support unstructured data like [JSON](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-json.html). This might serve your purpose.